# how many data points for effective LDA (clustering)?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning

Is there an advisable number of data points recommended to be able to effectively use LDA (Linear discriminant analysis)? I know this is a very open-ended question: but how many is enough?

Comment: How does this relate to clustering? Fisher's LDA is a supervised linear projection technique.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: as many as for PCA in *each* class.